# Error on fetch data, function instead of value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, axios, onclick

Hi guys I am trying to fetch data using get, and I want the data to be displayed after  I click on the button, as a normal crud
I am new in programming if there is someone that can help me. I APPRECIATE THANKS
everything in my backend is ok, I try in postman and console.log is everything good. My problem is only in this part thanks

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";



 function Usuarios() {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

     useEffect(()=> {
        const todosUsers = async () => {
            const res= await axios.get("/users");
            console.log(res)
            setUsers(res.data);
        }
        todosUsers()
    },[])
 
    return (
        <>
        <button onClick=
        {users.map((users) => ( 
            <h1>{users.username}</h1>
            ))}></button>
        </>

        )
}

export default Usuarios;
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Your onClick handler is defined in the wrong way. On the click event, set a variable to `true` in the state. If the variable is true, render the names of the user using the map as you are using now.

Answer (score 0):

one solution would be to keep a seperate variable to see if button is clicked as S.Singh mentioned

```js
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
```

and in your component you can set the `clicked` variable to `true` on click

```
 return (
        <>
        <button onClick={() => setClicked(true)}></button> //setting clicked true onclick
        {clicked && users.map((users) => (  //only renders when click is true
            <h1>{users.username}</h1>
         ))}
        </>

        )
```

if you want to hide and show alternatively on click just change the line to `onClick={() => setClicked(!clicked)}`

[codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/fetching-data-with-react-hooks-usestate-and-useeffect-forked-fwqcf?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
 {users.map((users) => ( 
        <h1>{users.username}</h1>
        ))
 }
```

from *onClick* definition and place it in an a markup where you want it to render. Define onClick hendler, which will be setting data from an API to a state

```
 import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
 import axios from "axios";

  function Usuarios() {
      const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

      const fetchOnClick = async () => {
          await axios.get("/users");
          console.log(res)
          setUsers(res.data);
      }

      return (
          <>
              <button onClick={fetchOnClick}>
                  Fetch
              </button>
              <div>
                  {users.map((users) => ( 
                      <h1>{users.username}</h1>
                  ))}
              </div>
         </>

    )
 }
```

OR

If you want to fetch the data inside useEffect hook, like you did in your example

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

     function Usuarios() {
         const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
         const [isContainerShowed, setIsContainerShowed] = useState(false)

         useEffect(() => {
             const res= await axios.get("/users");
             console.log(res)
             setUsers(res.data);
         }, [])

         const displayContainer = () => setIsContainerShowed(true);

         return (
             <>
                 <button onClick={displayContainer}>
                     Fetch
                 </button>
                 <div style={{display: isContainerShowed ? "block" : "none"}}>
                     {users.map(users => <h1>{users.username}</h1>)}
                 </div>
             </>

        )
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

use Effect hook runs every time the component is rendered but as I understand, you want to display users when the button is clicked, so you can fetch users once the button is clicked and display them using the code below

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

 function Usuarios() {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

    
    const fetchUsers= async () => {
            const res= await axios.get("/users");
            setUsers(res.data);
    }
 
    return (
        <>
          <button onClick={() => fetchUsers()}></button>
          {
             users.length && users.map(user => <h2>{user.username}</h2>) 
          }
        </>

        )
}
```

Comment: "use Effect hook runs every time the component is rendered" — No it doesn't. It has a dependency array of `[]` so it runs only the first time it is rendered.